# How to pass event parameters to event with different signatures

Tags: vb.net, events, plugins, event-handling

I'm trying to create plugin capability for my application. How do you AddHandle an event to a function which converts the event into a different event type.
For example, the plugin class contains the Sub and Event as follows:

```
Structure ClickedEventArgs
   property ClickedTime As DateTime
   property Clicked As Boolean
End structure

Sub Clicked(sender As object, e As ClickedEventArgs)
   RaiseEvent Clicked(Sender, e)
End sub

Sub PluginLoaded
    AddHandle ClickObject.Clicked, AddressOf NewObject.Clicked
End Sub
```

The NewObject is a Reference and can only handle events with the following structure (e as NewObjectEventArgs) and therefore, they cannot be AddHandled as the signatures are not the same.

```
Structure NewObjectEventArgs
    Property Clicked As Boolean
    Property ClickedTime As DateTime
    Property otherInfo As Object
End Structure
```

How do I convert the ClickedEventArgs to a NewObjectEventArgs and AddHandle them?

Do I use a function? and If so, how do I do this?

Comment: both event args should be classes not structures, and CA will like it if they inherit from EventArgs.  are you trying to "send along" an event, meaning catch A then throw B for something else to consume?  I dont follow what you are trying to say...NewObject just popped up in your post out of nowhere.  Is there any reason you cant use the correct signature?

Comment: The Plugin API allows you to send commands to the Main Application through a sub which raises an event. The application handles the object and updates the interface accordingly. The interface uses a reference DevExpress Component. The component demands (sender as object, e as itemclickeventargs) I would like to convert my own interface and populate the values into a new itemclickeventargs which will be sent to the event. Please help if you can, thank you.

Comment: still dont know what NewObject is and now there is a custom component.  You could perhaps subclass this thing and raise your own event.  Otherwise subscribe to it and forward the new event as Mark describes, you cant convert events or event args as the signature needs to remain the same for them to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to handle the events and forward them to `NewObject`:

```
Sub PluginLoaded()
    AddHandler ClickObject.Clicked,
        Sub(sender, e)
            NewObject.Clicked(
                sender,
                New NewObjectEventArgs() With {
                    .Clicked = e.Clicked,
                    .ClickedTime = e.ClickedTime,
                    .otherInfo = ??? ' leave null, or populate somehow
                }
            )
        End Sub
End Sub
```

If you need to remove the handler at some point, you should create a separate subroutine instead of using a lambda (or you can do it this way anyway, of you prefer):

```
Sub ClickObject_Clicked(sender As Object, e As ClickedEventArgs)
    ' Same code as above
End Sub
```